# Simplify PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, sql-delete

I have a PostgreSQL stored procedure that contains the following code:

```
IF something = TRUE THEN
    SELECT id INTO some_id FROM some_table WHERE some conditions LIMIT 1;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some conditions LIMIT 1;
ELSE
    SELECT id INTO some_id FROM some_table WHERE some OTHER conditions LIMIT 1;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some OTHER conditions LIMIT 1;
END IF;

DELETE FROM some_table where id = some_id;
```

Is there a way to  simplify the above code? I guess there is nothing we can do
about the repeated code in the `IF` and in the `ELSE`, but is there a way to avoid
having 2 `SELECT`'s every time? Is it possible to insert something in `some_id` while
`RETURN QUERY`?

Comment: You can use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ...` in newer versions and do it with a dynamic SQL string created with `format` and string concatenation.

Comment: Your `DELETE` statement never gets executed, because both of your `IF` branches has a `RETURN` statement.

Comment: @pozs: No. `RETURN QUERY` does not exit from the function (unlike `RETURN`).

Comment: @CraigRinger: No need for `EXECUTE` here. Nothing dynamic, just two cases.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter of course, my bad. That's just the silly syntax highlight, which does not emphasise `QUERY` -- `RETURN QUERY` really does not exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function does only what you posted then it is not necessary:

```
delete from some_table
where 
    something and (some conditions)
    or
    something is not true and (some other conditions)
returning *
```

Comment: Missed the `something IS NULL` case. If something can be NULL, then use or `something IS NOT TRUE` for the 2nd expression to do the same as the `IF` statement above (or OP needs to re-examine what to do for TRUE / FALSE / NULL).